# How to choose only one radio button using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've tried searching for questions similar to mine, only to find out that our circumstances aren't the same. So I'm posting this here.

I'm trying to create a list of questions where the methods of selection depends on the question, so question #1 can have radio buttons, question #2 can have checkboxes, and so on. One set lets the user choose the answer using radio buttons, however they're behaving like checkboxes (minus the unchecking). Am I missing something?

Below is my HTML:

```
<ul style="padding-left:30px;">
    <li ng-repeat="query in carousel.currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-init="carousel.checkboxCollection[query.id] = carousel.currentQuestionObject.init">
        <input type="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" ng-model="carousel.checkboxCollection[query.id]">
        <label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.question}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And below is my AngularJS that deals with the radio button answers:

```
{ inputType: "radio", init:false, question: "Tell us about your needs...", 
  choices: [
            { question: "Foo1", id: "qs1q1"},
            { question: "Foo2", id: "qs1q2"},
            { question: "Foo3", id: "qs1q3"},
            { question: "Foo4", id: "qs1q4"}
]},
```

And this is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. :) I'm sorry if this sounds silly...but can I use the same name for all of the radio buttons? Or do they have to be unique?

Comment: http://codepen.io/sp90/pen/GqdBEW

Comment: Maybe even make the id generic

Comment: http://codepen.io/sp90/pen/dXZjJX

Comment: It works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my solution below. Thank you Simon Pertersen for the guidance! Adding name really did the trick.

HTML:

```
<ul style="padding-left:30px;">
    <li ng-repeat="query in carousel.currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-init="carousel.checkboxCollection[query.id] = carousel.currentQuestionObject.init">
        <input name= "carousel.currentQuestionObject.name" type="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" ng-model="carousel.checkboxCollection[query.id]">
        <label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.question}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

AngularJS:

```
{ inputType: "radio", name: 'qs1needs', init:false, question: "Tell us about your needs...", 
            choices: [
                      { question: "Foo1", id: "qs1q1"},
                      { question: "Foo2", id: "qs1q2"},
                      { question: "Foo3", id: "qs1q3"},
                      { question: "Foo4", id: "qs1q4"}
]},
```